# Where is the native language setting for Swift or Objective-C in an existing Flutter project in Android Studio?

Tags: objective-c, swift, android-studio, dart, flutter

I've initially created a Flutter project with the native languages of Kotlin and Swift in Android Studio. Is there a way to change the native iOS language to Objective-C. This configuration only seems to occur on the creation of a Flutter project.

Comment: Good question. I started an app without Swift support and I'm wondering how to add it afterwards. Everything I've read unhelpfully says "Create your project like so...", which isn't helpful after weeks of development.

Answer (score 13):

- For **iOS** the difference is mostly in `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`
  and some different source code files are generated in `ios/Runner`
  (the differences are too many to list them here)
- For **Android** the differences are in `android/build.gradle`, `android/app/build.gradle`, and different source code files are generated in `android/app/src/main`

To switch languages you can delete the `ios` and/or `android` directory and run

```
flutter create -i swift -a kotlin .
```

If you made manual changes in files in these directories you need to re-apply them.

If you commit a project to Git and then switch language (as explained above), then it's easy to see what the differences are exactly.

Comment: Very nice answer, but I had to add the project's path at the end of the command line to make it works.
If you are in your project's folder, then run `flutter create -i swift -a kotlin .`

Comment: @Champe thanks for the hint/addition. That was an oversight.

Comment: don't delete the ios and android directories. doing so makes you loose all the changes and updates in your file. just do this flutter create -i swift -a kotlin .

Comment: If you use git you can apply your changes that you want to keep easily from a diff

Answer (score 3):

Don't delete the `ios` and `android` directories. doing so makes you loose all the changes and updates in your file. just this `flutter create -i swift -a kotlin .`

Don't forget the dot at the end , this specifies that you want to make the changes in the current directory not create a new one.

after you run this follow the instruction and your app will have Swift support for iOS and Kotlin for android.

To make sure that you have Swift support take a look at your runner folder and see if it contains

```
AppDelegate.siwft
```

Comment: Use Git and commit these directories then you can easily re-apply your manual changes after reinitializing them using a diff tool. This way you also get updates when the Flutter team makes changes to these files after you created the project.